# What do those numbers mean in the parenthesis after the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

*Don't mind the jQuery syntax. It serves as an example only and not the focus of the question.

```
$('target').on('click',function(){

           'do something'

       },5);
```

What does the value of 5 do? Does it set an initial value? Can you have multiple values like:

```
       },5,6,5);
```

or can you only have one value?

Comment: [Documentation link, for reference.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I mean, you can theoretically have as many arguments as you want to any function; it's up to the function body to work with those arguments

Comment: did you red the documentation? [.on() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Just noticed the "don't mind the jquery syntax". Without that clue, then, I have no idea what the question is about.  Function calls involve a list of parameters, and those are parameters, in a list.

Comment: does it work like an anonymous function?

Comment: It is not event valid syntax for jQuery 3. It will end with exception: 'jquery.js:4996 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on number '5''. jQuery can handle optional parameters, but your example is too much even for jQuery. Probably they're passing optional event data, but those have to be provided before callback fnc not after.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply function parameters. There is nothing special about the 2nd parameter, which happens to be a function. For the sake of clarity you could also refactor the code to look like this:

```
$('target').on('click', doSomething, 5);

function doSomething(){
    // do something
}
```

To see exactly what parameters you can pass to the `.on()` function I'd recommend reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Yes I think this is right. I haven't used the facility to pass stuff to an event handler like that in several years, but it does still exist (in jQuery). *However*, to do that, the value to be passed goes *before* the function (callback) parameter, not after. Thus I have no idea what the code in the OP thinks it's doing.

Comment: Your example will not work. It will end with error: 'jquery.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[g.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || g.handler).apply is not a function'  Try it yourself. You probably meant 5 as optional data, but it cannot be after doSomething, but have to be before.

Comment: @mauron85 I never said it was a good/valid jquery function, I was just using OP's code and explaining what the various parameters are

Answer (score 0):

This argument passes value to handler.

You can get value from event.data.

It must be single value.

If you want to pass multiple data, pass value by object.

```
$("button").on("click", 3, function(e) {
    alert(e.data) // alert 3
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/